# Is there a Vim-eqsue way to sequentially copy numbers?

Tags: vim

So I am trying to see if there is a Vim command or algorithm to where I can sequentially copy numbers.

So essentially, if I have variables `foo1` to `foo10`, is there a way to go from just:

```
foo1
```

to

```
foo1
foo1
foo1
foo1
foo1
foo1
foo1
foo1
foo1
foo1
foo1
```

to this:

```
foo1
foo2
foo3
foo4
foo5
foo6
foo7
foo8
foo9
foo10
```

or otherwise? Thank you.

Comment: Did you consider searching the documentation before asking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. [`{Visual}g CTRL-A`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#v_g_CTRL-A):

> Add `[count]` to the number or alphabetic character in the highlighted text. If several lines are highlighted, each one will be incremented by an additional `[count]` (so effectively creating a `[count]` incrementing sequence). For Example, if you have this list of numbers:
>
> ```
> 1. 
> 1. 
> 1. 
> 1.
> ```
>
> Move to the second "1." and Visually select three lines, pressing <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>CTRL-A</kbd> results in:
>
> ```
> 1. 
> 2. 
> 3. 
> 4.
> ```

However (tangential as it may be), while there is certainly a use case for this, "have variables `foo1` to `foo10`" is almost always a code smell. Most if not all programming languages have collection types like arrays/lists and dictionaries/hashes that address the need to have multiple grouped values.

Comment: Agree on the code smell part. There's rarely an excuse for having incrementally numbered variable names. If you write code like this, you *really* want to write `foo[0]` etc.